# Wordpress and WooCommerce to React and NodeJS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an eCommerce website running in the PHP ecosystem using WordPress as CMS and WooCommerce plugin to sell online products.

I have been doing well and most of the out of the box features implemented via free plugins has rapidly allowed me to implement various functionalities.

However, since I have a good customer base, I was planning to see if I can migrate this over to a normal public facing website and use the REST API endpoints for the users and eCommerce transactions.

Any ideas around this approach?

Comment: https://developer.woocommerce.com/2022/03/25/store-api-is-now-considered-stable/

Comment: @mujuonly i have seen that link, it seems to be another way to call the REST API. I am thinking to migrate off the WordPress website and create a web site using HTML CSS and bootstrap and in the backend import the database tables from Wordpress and connect to another backend such as NodeJS